# What happens when you use defaultProps when using redux with react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

Interseted in finding out what are the implications of using defaultProps when also using mapStateToProps from redux?

As an example:

```
class BasicComp extends React.Component{

    render() {
        return (<div>{this.props.content}</div>);
    }

}


BasicComp.defaultProps = {
    content: "some_text",
}


const mapStateToProps = (store, ownProps) => {

    return {
        content: ownProps.content || "some_other_text",
    }
}


const BasicCompRDX = connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(BasicComp)
```

I could test this and find the output, but would prefer an expert opinion as to how the redux deals with this at a philosophical level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the definition of **defaultProps**:

> defaultProps can be defined as a property on the component class itself, to set the default props for the class. This is used for undefined props, but not for null props.

Then simplify what your BasicCompRDX looks like:

```
class BasicCompRDX extends React.Component {
  // some react context - injection of redux store (dispatch, getState) API

  // some lifecycle hooks with `shouldComponentUpdate` implemented to optimize perf

  return() {
    const ownProps = this.props
    const stateProps = mapStateToProps(store.state, ownProps)
    const dispatchProps = mapDispatchToProps(store.dispatch, ownProps) || store.dispatch

    return <BasicComp {...stateProps, ...dispatchProps, ...ownProps} />
  }
}
```

Since your mapStateToProps function returns

> { content: ownProps.content || "some_other_text" }

and it will be passed to BasicComp as `<BasicComp content={ownProps.content || 'some_other_text"} content={ownProps.content} {...otherProps} />`, so obviously the content prop of BasicComp is defined with a fallback as 'some_other_text', thus defaultProps won't get used at all.

<sub>Disclaimer: not redux expert.</sub>

Comment: So basically defaultProps will only be used if the mapped state for a given prop is undefined

Comment: Great answer mate

Answer (score 0):

Here is the test results, seems like defaultProps are ignored when using connect.  Would love any insights from redux experts!?

Tests:

```
describe('BasicComp', () => {


    test('BasicComp init', () => {

        const component = render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BasicCompRDX />
            </Provider>
        );
        expect(renderToJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });


    test('BasicComp init with prop', () => {

        const component = render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BasicCompRDX content={"new content!!"}/>
            </Provider>
        );
        expect(renderToJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });


    test('BasicComp init no RDX', () => {

        const component = render(
            <BasicComp />
        );
        expect(renderToJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });


    test('BasicComp init no RDX with prop', () => {

        const component = render(
            <BasicComp content={"testing is useful!!"}/>
        );
        expect(renderToJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

});
```

Test Output:

// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`BasicComp BasicComp init 1`] = `

some_other_text

`;

exports[`BasicComp BasicComp init no RDX 1`] = `

some_text

`;

exports[`BasicComp BasicComp init no RDX with prop 1`] = `

testing is useful!!

`;

exports[`BasicComp BasicComp init with prop 1`] = `

new content!!

`;